# Own column or summary table for statistic data?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

For example we have three tables (Post, PostTag and Tag):

```
Post
=======
id
title
body

PostTag
=======
id
post_id
tag_id

Tag
=======
id
name
normalized_name
```

We need to count how much posts contain in a tag "sport". The count query is slow (we have some million rows).

For the solution we have to store the count in the database (after adding tags the count is updated with n + 1, after deleting n - 1).

The tags are added / removed frequently by community / moderation.

*My thoughts:*

Create own summary table for storing the number of tags:

```
 PostTagStat
 ========
 tag_id
 frequency
```

The index is created on column frequency.

But would it better if we add new column into Tag table to save INNER JOIN query like this:

```
 Tag
 ========
 id
 name
 normalized_name
 frequency
```

What do you think? Own table or new column? And why?

Comment: Does PostTag table have an index on tag_id field?

Comment: Of course! There is an index on tag_id field.

Comment: Can you post your query? I'd have thought that a simple query on post tag for a single tag_id  would be very quick.

Comment: It would be nice, if we focus on my question: own summary table or column for statistic data, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the query of data:

The choice between single table or two tables depends on which kind of query is used significantly more than another one.
If most of queries is about the tags' basic columns, two tables would have better performance. Single table would be better if most of queries require frequency of tags.

These two strategies, however, are hardly so different to performance because there is only one column(the "frequency" column, 4 bytes I guess) added.

---

For the modification of data:

The two tables strategy is slightly slower than one table strategy because databases need more logging for data of tables.

But I think the performance of modification is not your motivation **to add a column for quicker query**. So the performance of modification should not be the issue of your considerations.

---

After the system will be working time after time,  you may alter the strategy based on the facts of usage.